# Add Extra charges in shipping woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

using [XPS](http://xpsshipper.com) for Shipping rates. How can I add handling charges in shipping. 
like if the shipping charges rates `$39.52`, it should add `3$` in shipping rates ( like `42.52` ) even we can code in **function.php**[image].

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_handling' );
function woocommerce_custom_handling() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $shipping_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    if($shipping_method[0]){ 
        $handling = 3.00;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Handling', $handling, true, 'standard');
   }

}
```

To add directly to shipping costs: Since I don't know the shipping key for XPS this is my best guess to add it to all shipping methods, including XPS. See if this works

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates','woocommerce_custom_handling' );
function woocommerce_custom_handling($rates, $package) {
    $handling = 3.00;
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = ($handling + $rates[$rate_key]->cost);
    }
   return $rates;

}
```

Comment: i tried to find this slug, can we remove this condition and directly apply 3$ into shipping?

Comment: yes, now handling is separate with label.
can we add its 3 to shipping